altair grouped bar chart with quantitive axis
When using a quantitive x axis the xOffset does not seem to work in altair, i.e. the bars are stacked but I would like to have them next to each other. When encoding the x-axis as ordinal x=alt.X("Genre:O") it works, but the sorting is wrong. Any idea how to solve this?
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame(
    [[1, 5, "F"], [2, 10, "F"], [1, 3, "M"], [2, 9, "M"]],
    columns=["Genre", "Rating", "Gender"],
)

chart = (
    alt.Chart(data)
    .mark_bar()
    .encode(
        x=alt.X("Genre:Q", axis=alt.Axis(labelAngle=0)),
        xOffset="Gender",
        y=alt.Y("Rating", axis=alt.Axis(grid=False)),
        color="Gender",
    )
)

chart



What do you mean by  the sorting is wrong.

In this dummy example its fine, but my actual x axis has values between 0 and 100k

To display the bars next to each other instead of stacking them, you can use the alt.Column encoding to create separate plots for each genre and then use the alt.X encoding for the gender:
chart = (
    alt.Chart(data)
    .mark_bar()
    .encode(
        column=alt.X("Genre:Q"),
        x=alt.X("Gender:O"),
        y=alt.Y("Rating", axis=alt.Axis(grid=False)),
        color=alt.Color("Gender"),
    )
)

You could also change to sorting of the genders by changing the colour encoding line to x=alt.X("Gender:O", sort=["M", "F"]) if you wanted.
